# Parse Data From a Table and Make Result a PHP Variable

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, domdocument

Please assist! I am trying to build a PHP script that will do multiple functions. I have 2 mysql tables (I can't post pics yet so here are the descriptions):

PrimaryTable

```
ID    first    Last    phone              
1    Dan      Powers   5559876578         
2    Pete    Williams  5559023245
```

SecondaryTable

```
ID    user_id    First    Last      phone

1       2        Pete    Williams   5559023245
```

I need a PHP script that will allow you to search for a phone # from the first (PrimaryTable), get all the data from that table, and echo it in a html table. I have this part working, see code below:

```
<?php

 require 'Admin_connect.php';

 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM PrimaryTable';


 mysql_select_db('PrimaryTableDatabase');
 $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

 if(! $retval )
 {
   die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 if (!empty($_REQUEST['searchphone'])) {

   $searchphone = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['searchphone']);    
   $insert = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['insert']); 

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM PrimaryTable WHERE phone LIKE '%".$searchphone."%'"; 
   $r_query = mysql_query($sql); 

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){  

     $searchresults = '<tr>' . '<td headers="first_name">' .$row['first_name'] . '</td>' .
     '<td headers="last_name">' .$row['last_name'] . '</td>' .   
     '<td id="phoneresult">' .$row['phone'] . '</td>' .  
     '<td headers="Birthday">' .$row['Birthday'] . '</td>' .   
     '<td headers="Gender">' .$row['Gender']. '</td>' .
     '<td id="zip">' .$row['zip'] . '</td>' .
     '<td>' . '<input type="submit" value="Scan" name="Scan" />' . '</form>' . '</td>' . '</tr>';   
    }  

  }
?>
---------HTML----------
<form action="" method="post">  
Search: <input type="text" name="searchphone" /><br />  
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form>  

<table width="200" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
 <tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td>Phone:</td>
<td>Birthday:</td>
<td>Gender:</td>
<td>Zip:</td>
 </tr>
<?php echo $searchresults ?>
</table>
```

The next part has me stumped. I need to have a Submit button next to each row that shows up in the table (as you can see in the php above). When a user clicks that submit button it gets the phone # and name of the user displayed in the HTML table, selects all their information from the Mysql primaryTable (`SELECT * FROM PrimaryTable WHERE phone=(variable) && Last = (variable)`), and inserts all their information from the PrimaryTable into the SecondaryTable.

I think if I can find a way to turn the table `<td>` content into variables I can use them to SELECT and INSERT. But I don't know how to parse the HTML table in a way I can turn the phone # and name into their own variables. I've looked into DomDocument but can't seem to get it to work with what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet is to go with a javascript/ajax post for each line. To answer your question about getting data as postable variables add for example <input type='hidden' name='first_name' value='$row[first_name]' /> in each <td>

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be easier if you use the ID from the table (I am assuming the ID column is the primary key.) If you wrap your table in a form (`<form method="post"><table>...</table></form>`) then you can add a `<button>` element in each row like this:

```
'<td><button name="id" value="' . $row['id'] . '">Submit</button></td>'
```

When you click on the button it will submit the form with the corresponding id. Then you can get the id from `$_POST['id']`, be sure it's escaped properly, and let your database get the name and phone number for you instead.

```
INSERT INTO SecondaryTable 
SELECT id AS user_id, first, last, phone 
FROM PrimaryTable
WHERE id = $id
```